# How to trigger 'open in...' button on UIDocumentInteractionController?

Tags: ios, swift

I made viewController that have a UIDocumentInteractionController.

I previewed a pdf file on UIDocumentInteractionController.

I want to trigger 'open in' button on UIDocumentInteractionController after finished preview automatically.

[image]

Comment: Try using UIActivityViewController

Comment: @user9335240 Is it imposible to trigger 'open in' button using UIDocumentInteractionController?

Comment: @user9335240 I solved it using UIActivityViewController!! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it using UIActivityViewController.

```
let vc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [fileURL], applicationActivities: nil)
vc.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
vc.popoverPresentationController?.delegate = self
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```